# Replace pattern in file with pattern from a list, recursiv, per line

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying the following:

```
/dir1/textfile
/dir2/textfile
/dir3/textfile
```

"textfile" has always the same content, a simple number (400).

Now, I have a datafile with different numbers, and every value is on a new line (so one number per line)

What I would like to do is, to replace the value in "textfile" (400) with the values in the datafile, but the numbers must correspond with the entries in my datafile, so:

```
datafile
14
25
335
```

`14` should be written in `dir1/textfile`

`25` should be written in `dir2/textfile`

`335` should be written in `dir3/textfile`

and so on...

I played around with `sed`, but so far didn't find any working solution.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk '{print $0 > "dir"NR"/textfile"}' datafile
```

- `NR` expands to the current record number, so each line would be saved in `dir<line_number>/textfile` e.g. the first line would be saved in `dir1/textfile`, second would be in `dir2/textfile` and so on.

---

No need for the expensive `while` looping over the lines of the file, and do operation:

```
i=1; while IFS= read -r line; do echo "$line" >dir"$i"/textfile; ((i++)); done <datafile
```

The above shell way is just to show the method, you should follow the `awk` way.

---

**Edit based on comment:**

To replace all `400`s with the required numbers from `datafile`:

```
i=1; while IFS= read -r line; do sed "s/400/$line/g" dir"$i"/textfile; ((i++)); done <datafile
```

For editing the files in-place:

```
i=1; while IFS= read -r line; do sed -i "s/400/$line/g" dir"$i"/textfile; ((i++)); done <datafile
```

Original files backed up with `.bak` extension:

```
i=1; while IFS= read -r line; do sed -i.bak "s/400/$line/g" dir"$i"/textfile; ((i++)); done <datafile
```

Comment: That works nicely if I want to write the new values in my textfiles, but if I see this correctly it doesn't replace the value - meaning: now it overwrites any value given in the textfile. My goal is to replace this specific value here (that's why I looked at sed first). Is a replacement also possible with awk?

Comment: @Dieter Do the files contain anything other than just `400`? If not then it would be the same.

Comment: Unfortunately they do...sorry for the confusion

Comment: @Dieter Check my edits. Also please consider posting a precise idea while asking.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks. Next time I will be more precise